# Razor Pages: Passing query parameters in a link

Tags: razor-pages

I tried in the razor page:

```
<div>
    @foreach (var cat in Model.Categories)
     {
        
        <a asp-page="/Index?catId=@cat.Id">@cat.Name</a>
     }
    
</div>
```

And in the cs file:

```
public void OnGet()
        {
            CurPage = 1;
            CatId = -1;
            Search = "";
            HasCarousel = false;
            Title = "All Products";
            var queryParams = Request.Query;
            foreach(var qp in queryParams)
            {
                if (qp.Key == "curPage") CurPage = int.Parse(qp.Value);
                if (qp.Key == "catId") CatId = int.Parse(qp.Value);
                if (qp.Key == "search") Search = qp.Value;
                if (qp.Key == "hasCarousel") HasCarousel = bool.Parse(qp.Value);
            }
```

But when i click the link no query parameter is added to the address and the Request.Query is empty.
What am I doing wrong? Or what is the right way to pass the query parameters to a razor page via a link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add query parameters to your link you can use `asp-route-` in your `a` tag.
In your case it would look like

```
<a asp-page="Index" asp-route-catId="@cat.Id">@cat.Name</a>
```

You're also making receiving the query parameters in your OnGet() harder than it has to be. You can add parameters to your method signature like

```
OnGet(int catId)
```

and they will be passed in by the query parameters.